# Are BID and ASK the minimum and maximum?

Tags: stocks

I am interested in buying stock for my first time. I am using the broker E*Trade. When I look at some stocks it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYf82.png). Is the BID the minimum? I want to buy maybe 100 shares but I have to buy 3000?! Is the ASK the maximum? The ASK is not much a problem luckily. Please help!

Comment: oh, and I'm new to stackexchange so can I have a few upvotes?

Comment: This has to be a duplicate...

Comment: Please don't trade with real money until you have more experience with a 'mock' trading account [such as at Investopedia.com, or many other such 'training' sites]. A question such as this, while valid, indicates that you are at risk of making a poor transaction without knowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your screenshot, someone or some group of someones is willing to buy 3,000 shares at $3.45, and someone or some group of someones is willing to sell 2,000 shares at 3.88.

Without getting in to the specific mechanics, you can place a market buy order for 10 (or whatever number) shares and it will probably transact at $3.88 per share because that's the lowest price for which someone will currently sell their shares.

As a small fish, you can generally ignore the volume notations in the bid/ask quotes.

Comment: That was very useful. I'm glad I don't have to worry about that. Thank you!

Comment: I would even say that the bid/ask information is trivia, sorta like "34 people have looked at this auction" like you see on eBay.  At least for a heavily traded stock where you're a small fish and the numbers are close.